# Upload only few KB's of large file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On my rails app I have file fields and some text fields for url of remote server files, these file can be large in size ( 1-2 GB ) so i want to upload only few KB's to check initials of files.

I have installed paperclip but I am not sure if it can be done with this.

I tried with custom code as well but they all are uploading complete files.

Also looked into blueimp jquery upload but not sure how to us it with my for.

Following is my requirement in detail

App has a form with file fields and text fields for remote file urls ( to upload to server ), When user clicks on check button all files ( few kbs ) should be downloaded, run function to check all files and remove invalid files and then run function to upload complete files.

It there any tutorial or method or gem which for this type of requirement ?

Comment: I managed to upload files but code is writing complete file write now, so I added new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639004/stop-file-write-if-file-size-exceeds-500kb-ruby-on-rails