# Stop file write if file size exceeds 500KB ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, file, open-uri

How can I stop file writing ( upload form remote url ) when file size exceeds 500KB ?

I am using following code to upload a remote file

```
require 'open-uri'
open('temp/demo.doc', 'wb') do |file|
  file << open('http://example.com/demo.doc').read
end
```

this code is working properly and I am able to get files in temp folder. Now I want if filesize exceeds 500KB then it should stop writing file. In other words I want only 500KB of file if it is more than 500KB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IO#read](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-i-read), takes a bytes argument, so you can specify the size of what you want to read from IO as below:

```
require 'open-uri'
open('temp/demo.doc', 'wb') do |file|
  file << open('http://example.com/demo.doc').read(500000)
end
```

you can also play with things like `file.stat.size` but given you are piping directly to file you would have to do more things to get this to work.